# Assumptions in definition of "Log Pointwise Predictive Density" (LPD)

Tags: bayesian, predictive-models

In Equation 2 of [Vehtari (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.04544), the log pointwise predictive density is defined as

$$
  \text{lpd} 
    = \sum_{i=1}^n \log p(y_i | y)
    = \sum_{i=1}^n \log \int p(y_i | \theta) p(\theta | y) \text{ d}\theta
$$

I think I'm missing something obvious but this isn't easy to search.

Why is

$$
  p(y_i | y)
    = \int p(y_i | \theta) p(\theta | y) \text{ d}\theta
$$

and what are the assumptions?

Comment: Without checking the linked reference, this definition of the predictive density is agreeing with a Bayesian setting where (i) a prior $p(\theta)$ is chosen on $\theta$, (ii) $y$ is observed, (iii) the prior on $\theta$ is updated into $p(\theta|y)$, and (iv) the posterior predictive on future observations is computed as $$\int p(y^\prime | \theta) p(\theta | y) \text{ d}\theta$$

Comment: @Xi'an This question stemmed from a comment I got. Would a further assumption be that the new data $y_i$ (or $y'$) is conditionally independent of $y$.

That is, $y_i$ **must** be independent to $y$, conditional on $\theta$?

Comment: On reflection, the reference seems irrelevant and I am probably just asking for the deriviation of the posterior predictive distribution that I have taken as fact previously.